# Bootstrap Columns Centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have a basic HTML bootstrap layout like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <h2>Test Title</h2>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
h2{
  text-align: center;
}
```

The Title is correctly centered, but how can I move the `col-md-6`'s so that the title is directly in the middle of both of them?

An example of what I am typing about.

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/9eT2doccsc)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The title is in the middle. It it appearing different because both col divs are left aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `text-center` after the `col-md-6` items, or the row itself per your update to place both those divs in a row. Also, leave the header tag outside the row.

```css
h2{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <h2>Test Title</h2>

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h5>Test1</h5>
      <h5>Test1</h5>
      <h5>Test1</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h5>Test1</h5>
      <h5>Test1</h5>
      <h5>Test1</h5>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

See [this section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) of the Bootstrap documentation for details on typography related matters. You can also add this as a class to your h2 tag to center the title text if you wish.

Comment: i'd also recommend that the custom style on h2 be removed and the `text-center` class added to the title h2

Comment: @Punit Yep, updated my answer to say that, possibly just before or after you posted your comment. :D

Comment: Is there a reason both `.col-md-6` are not inside `.row`?

Comment: @hungerstar that was a mess-up  on my part. I fixed it

Comment: @hungerstar Yeah, I just copied what they had because the question was more about getting that styling down, but you're right, both `col-md-6` divs should be in a `row`. I'll update the answer to reflect OP's changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same CSS rule, and apply `text-center` to the `.col-md-6` divs, like so:

```
h2, 
.col-md-6 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Depending on which version of Bootstrap you're using, you should probably use `.center-block` or `.text-center`, rather than overriding Bootstrap's built in functionality.

Comment: Bootstrap has typography classes that can do this. No need for extra CSS.

Comment: See second half of answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `text-center` to the row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
      <h2>Test Title</h2>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
        <h5>Test1</h5>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example here: http://www.bootply.com/JvTYpubUeh#

Answer (score -1):

Try the margin Style Attribute
http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html

Create a class(or use bootstrap classes)

`#main {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}`

Comment: No, nope, don't do this. Bootstrap has styling classes to handle this, and in-line styling should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Besides, auto margins won't affect `.col-**` classes anyway, they're floated.